# H2 with border styling

Tags: css

I want to create h2 with this style 
[image]

CSS:

```
h2 {
    color: #158FFA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Code:

```
<h2>WHAT WE DO</h2>
```

But this only create a bottom line with a solid color. I want it with dark border beneath text.

Comment: an `<h2`> tag, (well all the hx tags), are block level elements by default. So the border will span the entire width of the element, you'll need to add `display:inline-block`. Or if you want the text to be centred, then you would need to wrap the text in a `<span>` like one of the answers suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your text with a span, and give that a darker border than the header. Then use positioning to bump the text down a pixel to line the borders up:

**HTML**

```
<h2><span>WHAT WE DO</span></h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    color: #158FFA;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    text-align:center;
}
span{
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #AAA;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/4dDJ6/1/)

*Or* if you wanted to use a pseudo element:

```
h2:before{
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #AAA;
    content:'What We Do';
}
```

The only issue here being that you need to add your text in the 'content' CSS property.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/4dDJ6/3/)

Comment: cant we do this with only h2 div?

Comment: yes i can use it, can you please tell me how can i do it with pseudo elements?

Comment: I'm afraid that's your only option with one element alone.

Comment: Please don't use the HTML `<kbd>` elements to decorate your links. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules